# Safely stop a thread from within the thread itself

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have an object that wraps a winsock, this is a simplified version:

```
struct Listener
{
    using accept_callback = void(*)(Client &&);

    ~Listener() { WSACleanup(); }

    Listener(const std::basic_string<TCHAR> &a_ip, std::uint16_t a_port, accept_callback a_callback)
    {
        // Error control ommited for brevity

        m_on_connection_accepted = a_callback;
        WSADATA sockets_data{};
        WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &sockets_data);

        m_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

        sockaddr_in service { .sin_family = AF_INET, .sin_port = htons(a_port) };
        InetPton(service.sin_family, a_ip.data(), &service.sin_addr);

        bind(m_socket, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR *>(&service), sizeof(service));
        listen(m_socket, SOMAXCONN);

        m_listen_thread = std::jthread([&]
        {
            while (m_socket != INVALID_SOCKET)
            {
                if (SOCKET client = accept(m_socket, NULL, NULL); client == INVALID_SOCKET)
                    break;
                else
                    m_on_connection_accepted(std::move(Client{ client }));
            }
        });

    }

    void stop()
    {
        closesocket(m_socket);
        m_socket = INVALID_SOCKET;

        if (m_listen_thread.joinable())
            m_listen_thread.join();

        m_listen_thread = {};
    }

private:

    accept_callback m_on_connection_accepted{ nullptr };
    SOCKET m_socket{ INVALID_SOCKET };
    std::jthread m_listen_thread{};
};
```

My goal is stop the listener as soon as a client is connected so no more than one client is connected at once:

```
void on_client_connected(sockets::Client &&a_new_client)
{
    // … do things …

    m_listener.stop();
}
```

This code causes an `abort()` call, because accepting the client causes the listening thread to join from a call within the thread itself: *thread loop* → `m_on_connection_accepted(…)` → `on_client_connected(…)` → `Listener::stop()` → `jthread::join()`.

I thought that the outcome would have been:

1. `m_socket` is set to `INVALID_SOCKET`.
2. Thread joins.
3. Thread keeps going after `m_on_connection_accepted` call.
4. Thread loop condition is not met.
5. Trhead finishes.

Obviously I was wrong so how should I do in order to achieve my goal?

Comment: *"I thought that the outcome would have been ... 2. thread joins 3. thread keeps going"* Nope. the join call only returns after the thread has been joined which only happens, after the thread's logic is done...

Comment: you should get error  `resource_deadlock_would_occur` by join self [per cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join)

Comment: `m_on_connection_accepted(std::move(Client{ client }));` you don't need `std::move` here. Temporary objects can be bound to rvalue references...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My goal is stop the listener as soon as a client is connected so no more than one client is connected at once:

If I only wanted to service one client at a time, I simply wouldn't create a thread to service the client at all.

It appears that what you want is a sequence like:

```cpp
for (;;) {
    auto client = listen_for_client_connection();
    service(client);
}
```

The whole point of listening in one thread and servicing the client in another thread is so when one client connects, you can service that client, *and* immediately listen for new connections, so you can serve multiple clients concurrently.

Since you only want to serve one client at a time, then...just don't do any of that "stuff" intended solely for servicing multiple concurrent clients. To service only one client at a time, you only need one thread of execution.